# How to transpose in SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, mariadb

This is my SQL query:

```
'{select id,value,
    case when temp.country-id=2 then
                          interval 4 hour + cast(time as time ) else
                          interval 3 hour + cast(time as time ) end as TIME
from temp}'
```

This is the output I am getting for above query:

[image: This is the output I am getting for above query]

I want this output using SQL:

[image: I want this output using SQL]

Comment: Please don’t link to images of data. Add the data as editable text to your question. It makes it difficult to understand your question if not all the information is visible at the same time. Also, if someone wants to test a solution they need to be able to copy your data rather than having to manually type it in themselves

Comment: i try to copy and paste data here it show as add image

Comment: database engine is maria db and spark sql

Comment: The Markdown processor in Stack Overflow understands tables, [see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post).

Comment: I've added MariaDB as a tag - not sure how you are using both Maria _and_ SparkQL though - you may need to be more specific about which dialect of SQL you are using.

Comment: actually i  have spark sql in amazon glue to run this query which uses spark sql and mariadb is for testing

Comment: are you tried pivot concept after formatting time?